# PowerShell script to compute partial MD4 checksums

Tags: powershell, hashing, checksum

I need a script that will read an input file and calculate MD4 checksums for each 9728000 bytes chunk, until the end of the file. I've done this previously by first extracting all 9728000 bytes chunks as individual files, then computing the MD4 checksum for each with a command line tool called [fsum](http://www.slavasoft.com/fsum/index.htm), but that's not convenient, especially with large files.

From what I could gather, PowerShell can natively compute MD5 checksums, but not MD4.

I did tests with the following script, adapted from code obtained [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238275/quickly-copy-short-string-from-binary-file-as-hex-to-text-file-in-loop-part), and which I still don't fully understand.

```
$input = Read-Host "File name"
$file = Get-Item -LiteralPath $input
$offset = 0
$length = $file.length
$name = $file.name
$hasher = [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm]::Create('MD5')
for ($offset -lt $length) {
    $buffer = [Byte[]]::new(9728000)
    $stream = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($file.FullName, 'Open', 'Read')
    $stream.Position = $offset
    $readSize = $stream.Read($buffer, 0, 9728000)
    $md5 = $hasher.ComputeHash($buffer, 0, $readSize)
    $stream.Dispose()
    echo "$md5 $offset" >> "$name MD5.txt"
    $offset = $offset + 9728000
}
```

Results were as follows :

```
78 224 90 67 158 49 86 127 118 179 251 89 133 103 144 25 0
190 40 170 149 51 93 153 191 212 194 162 165 38 124 57 96 9728000
160 20 197 150 189 246 209 156 212 84 154 21 200 7 148 228 19456000
...
```

But 1) this is not the layout I need, 2) I need MD4 specifically, and 3) another issue is that the loop doesn't stop even when there's no more data to read, despite the `$offset -lt $length` condition (I must be doing it wrong).

What I need is regular 32 bytes MD4 strings :

```
908CB75033311ADCB0FBCD0DCD869050 0
A1211C1B77C0EFFA98DB8F719AB30A93 9728000
D9719A4CB32F2D350CB39A0CB790424B 19456000
...
```

Then today I found [this MD4 script](https://github.com/LarrysGIT/MD4-powershell). I tried to use it by adapting the above script, but [failed misebarly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJjCxjS7zTo&t=1650). Also, the function was not recognized if I copied the entire content of the script (starting with `function Get-MD4...`) within my own script, it works only if calling the script through “dot-sourcing” (a concept I discovered along the way while spending about 2 hours on this, sifting through several 400+ pages PDF books on PowerShell which barely helped otherwise). Could it be due to a formatting issue ? (If I open the md4.ps1 script in Notepad2, it says that the line endings are “LF”, whereas my script has “CR+LF” line endings. It's not the main issue but it really pi***d me off this afternoon so I'd like to know what was going on.)

The [README file](https://github.com/LarrysGIT/MD4-powershell/blob/master/README.txt) for that script contains this :

> ```
>  This is a MD4 algorithm function wrote in powershell.
>  
>  PS> Get-MD4 -String 'abc' -UpperCase
>  A448017AAF21D8525FC10AE87AA6729D
>  
>  PS> $b = @('abc'.ToCharArray() | %{[int]$_})
>  PS> Get-MD4 -bArray $b
>  a448017aaf21d8525fc10ae87aa6729d
> ```

I don't understand the line that starts with `$b =`  and I have no idea how I could find something relevant either in those PDF books or from a Web search. So once again, I'm at a loss.

What would be the most efficient way of reading a file one size-defined chunk at a time, feeding that as an input for the `Get-MD4` function, then incrementing the $offset value, and so on, until the end of the file ? Should I use `-String` or `-bArray` ?

The goal, if that matters, is to check files which are shared on the eDonkey network but with a non matching ED2K checksum. For instance, I have a 4GB MKV file, doing a search with eMule I found a MKV file with the exact same size but a different ED2K checksum, so I want to know which specific parts are different (ED2K checksum is the MD4 checksum of the list of MD4 strings for each 9728000 bytes chunk, which can be found in the metadata file), then I can download specifically those parts in order to check if the corrupted version of that file is the one I have or the one which is currently shared. Hope it's clear. Otherwise, nevermind, let's focus on the subject at hand which is “Calculate partial MD4 checksums”.

Comment: What do you mean by it fails? The output is not as expected or are there any errors? `$b = @()` is simply storing the result of the expression to the variable `$b`. And (dot)-sourcing is well-known if you've used other shells, because each script runs in its own shell so the environment (including defined functions) will be lost when the script exits

Comment: It means I don't know how to complete the code I have (which was used for a completely different task) to get the correct input for the md4 script. My knowledge of PowerShell is still very cursory,, and each time I try to do something new on my own with PDF books or Web searches, I get lost very quickly. I'm not sure what the $buffer / $stream / $readSize lines do exactly, how they're supposed to interact, or even if I'm on the right track toward something that should work as intended. As for `$b`, I'm not sure what `ToCharArray` does (only 1 hit in a 428 pages PDF), same for `%{[int]$_}`.

Comment: So few suggestions, one focus on the problem, you are not attempting to use md5 your attempting to use md4.  ToCharArray converts a string into a character array. $stream is the reader (I.e the handle to the file). $readsize is the number of chars (bytes) that will be read likewise in order to read characters with a file stream you need a $buffer. These are very programming basic concepts. The md5 script reads the content of the file. Up to 9728000 Bytes will be read and put into the buffer which is the same size and then the md5 hash is calculated.

Comment: [Might be easier to code your own md4 library then call it from your PowerShell script](https://github.com/novotnyllc/cifs/blob/master/Cifs/MD4.cs)

Comment: How would it be easier to code my own md4 library if I obviously lack very basic programming concepts ? So it is not possible to achieve what I want with the md4 script I mentioned ? Why would that be ? I mentioned MD5 to show that I had tried something, even though that's not what I want... Generally it's supposed to be appreciated when someone asks a question after trying something, even if it's stupid or barely relevant...

Comment: @GabrielB - Your sample script is inefficient. Your going to need to learn more about programming to use md4 the way you want

Comment: That line starts with `$b` converts string 'abc' to a character array and converts the code points for each character to an integer and assigns the resultant array to variable `$b`. You need to use `-bArray` for binary files, just read the bytes of a file and convert to integer array then pass that as argument to `Get-MD4`.

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος Thanks, but how can I do that, reading the bytes from a file (9728000 at a time, then what's left for the last chunk), converting that as an integer array which can be passed as an argument to Get-MD4 ? By any chance, do you know of a simpler / more efficient method to do that ? (WinHex for instance can compute checksums for blocks of data, but it would be too tedious for hundreds of blocks. I know a CLI tool called dsfo which can compute MD5 checksums for user-defined blocks of data, but only MD5, whereas CLI tools I know which can compute MD4 only accept files as input.)

Comment: @GabrielB - 1. You don't need a PhD in programming to understand the algorithm associated with MD4, and technically that would be a PhD in Math not Programming, since MD4 is based on Math.  2.  I thought I was at least sort of helpful, I provided an explanation to the variables, but perhaps that explanation wasn't clear. 3. Looks like you got your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code above is highly inefficient because a new huge buffer and a new stream is created every loop iteration. The [stream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=net-6.0) already handles offsets and everything for you so the loop body is actually very simple:

```powershell
Param (
    [parameter(Mandatory)][string]$InputFile,
    [int]$ChunkSize = 9728000
)

. .\md4.ps1
# Or copy the md4.ps1 content here, or add to the $PROFILE

class Md4Info {
    [string]$Checksum
    [int]$Offset
}

$stream = [IO.FileStream]::new($InputFile, [IO.FileMode]::Open, [IO.FileAccess]::Read)
$buffer = [Byte[]]::new($ChunkSize)
while (($readSize = $stream.Read($buffer, 0, $ChunkSize)) -gt 0) {
    [Md4Info]@{
        Checksum = Get-MD4 -bArray $buffer[0..$readSize]
        Offset = $stream.Position
    }
}
$stream.Dispose()
```

That's a huge improvement over your code, but obviously it isn't the *the most efficient way* because the [md4.ps1](https://github.com/LarrysGIT/MD4-powershell) script above was written for a very old PowerShell version and is hugely inefficient. It also handles Unicode incorrectly so using `-String` may return a corrupted output. Anyway you can try it by saving my updated code above as a *.ps1 file such as `Get-ChunkMd4.ps1`. Sample output:

```
PS D:\test> .\Get-ChunkMd4.ps1 D:\test\file.txt

Checksum                         Offset
--------                         ------
11cf3ecf1a3a9d1b270c9e313901441d      0

PS D:\test> .\Get-ChunkMd4.ps1 D:\test\file.mp4 -ChunkSize 1MB

Checksum                          Offset
--------                          ------
8932ec620ef5df53f519e6271931bc0d       0
92a8f97be075655bfd1e8670368ff2a3 1048576
c6ec8e0d67b42cc3a9a1bc9d5c9fa8f0 2097152
1339bac99b94397b5848d1d86b0cc49e 3145728
fd643f329daeb73e07e24194fd1b0a31 4194304
```

That said, you can never have the **most** efficient way unless you write some highly efficient parallel code with hardware acceleration and/or SIMD and compile to native code. A native MD4 library may run thousands or millions of times faster than the script above. In fact a good hashing library using AVX-512 can hash at **3-30 GB/s** or more, but `md4.ps1` is so bad that it needs 4 minutes just to hash a tiny 8.2 MB file on my machine (Ryzen 5 4600H) which is **~29.5 KB/s!!!** Rest assure that you can't even hash the video file quickly enough as you download them. You should really find one such 3<sup>rd</sup> party library/tool and feed them data with the loop above

---

Also note that if you use a function a lot then you should add it to the profile like this

```
Add-Content -Path $profile -Value ". .\md4.ps1"
```

Now you can just remove the `. .\md4.ps1` in your script because the function will be loaded everytime PowerShell is run

Comment: Alright, thanks for that, I was beginning to lose hope of getting something actually useful! It certainly is an improvement since my code didn't work at all for MD4. Indeed the very low performance is a deal breaker here (files I need to process are typically 1GB+). Any idea where I can find an efficient MD4 library that would accept a PowerShell stream (if that's the correct terminology) as input? I mentioned fsum, which is efficient enough for my purposes, but it only accepts individual files as input.

Comment: Also, could you briefly explain why a variation of the code I copied was proposed on the linked StackOverflow page if it's so inefficient? The purpose was different, it was meant to extract one short string for each of thousands of large files — that might be the reason, each loop processed a different file, whereas here the same file is read sequentially at different offsets. Then why did Get-MD4 fail when I dragged-and-dropped the content of the script into my script? Could it be because of a line endings mismatch as I surmised?

Comment: Someone above mentioned [this script](https://github.com/novotnyllc/cifs/blob/master/Cifs/MD4.cs), is it possible to use it in the same way, and would it be reasonably efficient? Should it be compiled first and how? I did a Web search with keywords “command line md4 offset”, first two hits are my own two threads here and on Reddit... I'm quite used to that, needing the answer to a question which noone in the whole world ever asked...

Comment: So lacking a better solution I tried your script with Get-MD4, and indeed it's about as sluggish as you warned it would be, I got 4 checksums in about 20min, it would take the whole night to process a 4GB file. A small issue is that the Offset values are shifted (first should be 0). Then I had trouble specifying the InputFile parameter, it would fail if the path inputted had any space, or apostrophe, it would fail with quotation marks, and if typing the file name only while its folder was already open in PowerShell, it would fail saying that no such file is in "C:\User\[username]".

Comment: Apart from the MD4.cs script mentioned above, could the [QuickHash](http://www.slavasoft.com/quickhash/index.htm) library (from the same company as fsum) be used for that purpose, and how?

Comment: library suggestion is off-topic here, try [softwarerecs.se] instead. You can try anything you want and choose what's acceptably fast. The above QuickHash was so ancient that I doubt it even uses modern SIMD and will just be as sluggish, although being native I expect it to be a thousand times faster than md4.ps1. Don't think about having efficient hash in C# either, you'll have to use modern vector types in .NET but it'll still far slower than native code

Comment: I don't know about eDonkey and why they use such outdated hashing algorithms. No one cares writing efficient modern code for a thing that almost no one uses. Anyway there are too many questions here, please post another different question on superuser. Comments are generally not for asking and answering questions

Comment: you can easily run a loop in powershell to feed `fsum` your files. I don't understand what you mean by `why did Get-MD4 fail when I dragged-and-dropped the content of the script into my script?` What output or error does it produced. And no, the first offset is 0 as I showed in the example output

Comment: But the goal is to compute checksums for each 9728000B chunk of a file, `fsum` only accepts a file's path as input. I can extract all chunks first but that's what I'd like to avoid. / In my first attempts, I inserted the complete code from the MD4.ps1 script at the end of my script (by drag-and-drop with Notepad2), and I got errors saying “The term 'Get-MD4' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program”. / For some reason, in my test result the first offset was 9728000 (with the MD4 value corresponding to the first chunk).

Comment: As for eDonkey, it's a peer-to-peer protocol created around 2000, I guess that once such a standard is defined and implemented, it can't be changed for reasons of backward compatibility, even if it becomes technically outdated. / The rules here are highly frustrating. I have an issue and I'm looking for a solution, I'm being told that I should know what I don't know, then that the one tool I found is very inefficient but suggesting another would be off topic, and it is discouraged to discuss anything for longer than 3 or 4 messages, so I usually give up before I get a working solution...

Comment: powershell parses scripts from top to bottom so if you insert the function at the end then obviously it won't work. Any symbols must be declared before they're used. The point is that if you don't have any other better tools then the only thing you can do is save each chunk to files and call `fsum` if you don't want to write a tool that receives a file offset. No one uses this, that's why it's hard to find support. You can improve this by saving to RAM disk for example, and also run multiple `fsum` instances in parallel

Comment: That explains it (if I put the script at the end, doesn't work, at the beginning, fails too, where you put “or copy content here”, it works). I'm used to Avisynth (video editing environment) which recognizes functions even at the end of a script. // A CLI program doing partial checksums would certainly have applications. I know only one program doing this, and only for MD5, called [dsfok](https://tinyurl.com/3t4j9pka), no longer developped (its primary purpose is to extract data blocks from files or storage devices, I use it quite often). / Thanks for the RAM disk tip, I'll look into that.

Comment: scripting languages are run by interpreters which parse commands line-by-line so obviously you can't put things at the end and expect the interpreter to see. Even compiled languages typically require you to declare from top to bottom. Only a few modern *compiled* languages have multi-pass parsing so it'll know identifiers at a later point